# Mongodb cannot start when building new app with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This question has been bothering me for a long time. I use meteor to build an [app from github](https://github.com/Hitachi-Automotive-And-Industry-Lab/semantic-segmentation-editor) for annotation , but after an unexpected shutdown, meteor was unable to restart the application. Specifically, when I run `meteor npm start`, I got the error:

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.

Unspecified unrecoverable error. Exit was not clean
```

I'm using meteor at 1.12 and ubuntu 1604 LTS (not in the virtual machines), and I actually tring to reinstall the whole meteor and the github project, and still got same problem. How can I fix the problem of mongodb inside the Meteor?

Comment: Probably your Mongodb was corrupted. If the data can be erased, do `meteor reset`.

Comment: I tried. However, It doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to run the project with `meteor run` too?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I sovle this problem by installing a stand-alone mongodb on the system, and run `MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 meteor npm start`. I think the mongodb inside the meteor is somehow corrupted and cannot be recoverd even by reinstalling meteor.

Comment: Very weird. Usually when you execute `meteor reset` you are cleaning the database. But you can delete manually the DB folder: `.meteor/local/db` . Try this.